# Will this H-Bridge and it's driver work?

Tags: h-bridge, inverter, high-frequency

I am creating a half bridge, I though about it a bit and came up with this idea
First for the controlling side we have a typical 555 timer wired up like this

[image: http://prntscr.com/4gji2e]

(But the resistors are variable resistors to adjust output frequency)
It's output is then fed into a mosfet driver (Which i don't know how to quite use yet)( It is an IR 2112) in this way 
[image: http://prntscr.com/4gk1kv]
and then the mosfet driver's output is connected to the two mosfets in my Half bridge, Is skipping a gate drive transformer safe for this?
Also,Is all the wiring correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can skip the transformer; this type of driver chip is specifically designed to replace transformers.

I can't answer about "all the wiring", since you haven't shown it to us. You've only shown us snippets.